# getting CalendarList from google calendar

Tags: asp.net, google-calendar-api

I am trying to get the calendarlist from Google calendar using ASP.NET version 3 calendarAPI. It is working fine for all the user i am having, but only a single use is saying that he is unable to get his primary calendar on to my project. I have degub his complete account and in calendarlist i am unable to find his primary calendar but in real he is having his calendar in google calendar account. So is it possible to hide the calendar in google calendar account. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using this method to retrieving calendars: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/list? This method contains additional parameter `showHidden`. Try to set it to `true` and invoke it for user for which you weren't able to retrieve primary calendar.

Comment: Thanks Michal, Now i am able to find that calendar, but still we have the problem that he is not having the primary calendar. But according to my information, every account should have one primary calendar. as it is also not possible to delete that particular calendar.

Comment: Done find the calendar. It was stored in next page token. thank you so much.

Comment: Please, add the answer to your question where was a problem and how you fixed it. I think, it may help to someone else in the future.

Comment: While retrieving the calendarlist from google calendar, it will fetch maximum of 100 calendars in a single query. So the solution for this is either to use Paging or to set the maxresult property in the request. In my case i was unable to find the primary calendar because it was at 115 position. So after setting the maxfield property it was working for me.

Comment: Add it as an answer not as a comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

While retrieving the calendarlist from google calendar, it will fetch maximum of 100 calendars in a single query. So the solution for this is either to use Paging or to set the maxresult property in the request. In my case i was unable to find the primary calendar because it was at 115 position. So after setting the maxfield property it was working for me.